# Преобразование to_number в индексе

Tags: sql, oracle, index

Пытаюсь построить индекс по текстовому полю (v2, хранятся только числа) с преобразованием к числу.

```
create index i_cvb on tbl(to_number(v2));
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01722: неверное число
```

Насколько понимаю, так сделать не получится?
Планировал использовать индекс для поиска вхождения значения '<>'.

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Comment: Думаю, если вы сделаете `select to_number(v2) from tbl` - получите такую же ошибку. Скорее всего в поле есть значение, которое не получается преобразовать в число

Comment: Спасибо, проверю. С ограничениями в условии select to_number отрабатывало, видимо не попадалось ошибочное значение.